# Indication for footnote is not on right place

Tags: header-footer, cyrillic

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newfont{\xrm}{wncyr10 scaled 1000}
\newfont{\xbfh}{wncyb10 scaled \magstep4}

\newcommand{\ch}{ch}
\newcommand{\Ch}{Ch}
\newcommand{\cy}{\symbol{'17}}
\newcommand{\Cy}{\symbol{'07}}
\newcommand{\dz}{\symbol{'12}}
\newcommand{\Dz}{\symbol{'02}}
\newcommand{\dy}{dj}
\newcommand{\Dy}{Dj}
\newcommand{\sh}{sh}
\newcommand{\Sh}{Sh}
\newcommand{\zh}{zh}
\newcommand{\Zh}{Zh}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}

       \xbfh NEKA\footnote{\xrm ovde stoji ne\sh to} RE\Ch ENICA

    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image: a busy cat]
Problem is 1 in title (for footnote), is not on appropriate place (it should be at the top of word). It's probably because I use different font (then standard), but I a beginner in Tex and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist in using the OT2 encoded fonts, do it properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT2]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{wncyr}

\newcommand{\cy}{\symbol{'17}}
\newcommand{\Cy}{\symbol{'07}}
\newcommand{\dz}{\symbol{'12}}
\newcommand{\Dz}{\symbol{'02}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\huge
NEKA\footnote{ovde stoji neshto} RECHENICA
\end{center}

\cy${}={}$c1

\Cy${}={}$C1

\dz${}={}$d2

\Dz${}={}$D2

\end{document}
```

You can see how to input the Serbian characters without commands. In the image the text height has been reduced for showing the footnote without blank space.

[image]

You can also use direct Cyrillic input, so long as you use UTF-8 as input encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT2]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{wncyr}

\newcommand{\cy}{\symbol{'17}}
\newcommand{\Cy}{\symbol{'07}}
\newcommand{\dz}{\symbol{'12}}
\newcommand{\Dz}{\symbol{'02}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\huge
NEKA\footnote{ovde stoji neshto} RECHENICA \\
НЕКА\footnote{овде стоји нешто} РЕЧЕНИЦА
\end{center}

\cy${}={}$c1${}={}$ћ

\Cy${}={}$C1${}={}$Ћ

\dz${}={}$d2${}={}$џ

\Dz${}={}$D2${}={}$Џ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much for help. What is different between first and second solution (expect that in second we can write овде стоји нешто directly, I can't see what else). Maybe you want NEKA REČENICA or?

Comment: And one question more: if I use second option, how can I use English alphabet again (for example, I have some English link)? Before I used '\rm' command, but now?

Comment: @Cortizol I suggest you to use the T2A encoding instead and `babel`.

Comment: OK, but I have problem with installing `babel`. I find some manual on Serbian: first, I downloaded this http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/serbianc/tex/generic/serbianc two file. Then I input them in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel. Next step is to add \DeclareOption{serbianc}{\input{serbianc.ldf}} in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty which I did it. And next is to edit language.dat in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\config, to add % from hyphen-serbianc:
serbianc loadhyph-sr-cyrl.tex, but I can't find language.dat :/

Comment: @Cortizol Do a full install of the TeX system

Comment: You mean to reinstall MiKTeX? Oh, ok, if you say so.

Comment: I have one problem: when I type \Sh for Ш I get Čx :/ (for small letter everything is all right)

Comment: @Cortizol If I type “Sh”, that's the same as using `\Sh` with your definition, I get “Ш”.

Comment: I am sorry, it's my fault. I mean Sh, not \Sh. (I am using your way for writing (it all working except this tiny problem))

Comment: @Cortizol I don't know what to say: in my test it's correct.

Comment: It's ok now. I fixed problem. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5):

Using font commands is not the way to go in LaTeX. You are magnifying the font, the footnotemarker is not influenced by this. Use LaTeX commands like `\huge` for this stuff.

Especially when writing non-Latin scripts, the TeX engines XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are beneficial. They naturally support UTF-8 (Unicode) and you can input the Cyrillic characters directly. In the following example the [`libertine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine) font is used.

As I do not speak Russian, I cannot tell what the words actually read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\uppercase{\Huge\bfseries нека\footnote{ожде стойи несто} реценица}
\end{center}

Wikipedia about LaTeX: 

LaTeX — наиболее популярный набор
макрорасширений (или макропакет) системы компьютерной вёрстки
TeX, который облегчает набор сложных документов. В типографском
наборе форматируется как \LaTeX.  

\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system and document markup
language.
\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem. `:)` I normally edit posts if I think there are spelling errors or formatting issues.